# Why is scrappy shell in command line trying to autocomplete my commands and running to the next line?

Tags: terminal

I am using Terminal on Mac. When I enter scrapy shell 'website url', terminal starts trying to autocomplete my code and it becomes very hard to type. Code runs onto the next line. This error only occurs in the shell, not in normal terminal.

At the bottom of the screen, it says

[F4] Emacs 1/1 [F3] History [F6] Paste mode [F2] Menu - CPython 3.7.3

It never used to display this status. I would like to turn autocomplete off so I can use the shell normally.

In Terminal Preferences, I tried selecting 'Restore Default Profiles'. This did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs was open within scrapy shell. I uninstalled the package and it worked.