# Scrapy shell terminal has an emacs extension that autocompletes my commands

Tags: terminal, emacs, scrapy

[image: Emacs Extension on my command Prompt]

Emacs Extension on my command Prompt

This extension
"[F4] Emacs 1/1 [F3] History [F6] Paste mode [F2] Menu - CPython 3.9.4)"
auto completes my commands on scrapy shell.
I checked [Why is scrappy shell in command line trying to autocomplete my commands and running to the next line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57332846/why-is-scrappy-shell-in-command-line-trying-to-autocomplete-my-commands-and-runn) but it didn't help since i need Scrapy shell to run my scraping projects [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57332846/why-is-scrappy-shell-in-command-line-trying-to-autocomplete-my-commands-and-runn)

I also tried [how to completely uninstall emacs on windows](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/2t9wkc/how_to_completely_uninstall_emacs_on_windows/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)
but the solution didn't help since I cannot locate the file in my directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying most of the tricks, I settled for uninstalling python. I installed it a fresh and it got rid of the extension.